# Можно ли сделать из объекта функцию?

Tags: javascript

Можно ли после создания объекта, сделать его "вызываемым", как функцию?

```
const obj = {}
// какие-то манипуляции
obj()
```

Не то чтобы я собрался это как-то применять, но интересны сама возможность и методы с помощью которых этого можно достичь.

И если нельзя, то почему?

Comment: сразу понятно человек пришёл из php с возможностями __invoke  %)

Comment: вовсе нет, я просто исхожу из, возможно ошибочной концепции, что "почти все в JS - это объект", а функция - частный случай объекта, к которому можно применить "скобочки" (). И отличаются объекты, по большему счету прототипом. Я пытался изменить прототип {}, на прототип функции - но как-то это ни к чему не привело...

Comment: Можно использовать функцию как объект, но не объект как функцию. Т.е. можно написать вот так function example(){}; example.property = 'value'. Ещё объект можно обернуть в js Proxy и отлавливать вызовы, но это думаю не то, что вам нужно

Comment: @Anynomius, в прокси не будут отлавливаться методы call/apply если target не функция

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Это сделать невозможно.

Чтобы объект был вызываемым, необходимо, чтобы у него был *внутренний* метод `[[Call]]`.

Так как данный метод относится к внутренним, его невозможно изменить/добавить непосредственно из скрипта.

Answer (score 1):

Разве что, создав новую ссылку

```
const obj = {
  foo: 'bar',
};

const fn = () => console.log('baz')

Object.setPrototypeOf(fn, obj)

fn() // 'baz'
console.log(fn.foo) // 'bar'
```